# When sent USDT, I get error {'code': -32000, 'message': 'insufficient funds for gas * price + value'}

Tags: python, ethereum, erc20, web3py

I send contract ERC-20(USDT) in mainnet.
My method:

```
def contract_transfer(data: ContractTransafer):
    try:
        client = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(data.url))
        contract_address = TEST_USDT_CONTRACT if os.getenv('DEBUG') else USDT_CONTRACT
        contract = client.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=contract_abi())

        address_from = Web3.toChecksumAddress(data.from_address)
        address_to = Web3.toChecksumAddress(data.to_address)
        nonce = client.eth.get_transaction_count(address_from)
        gas_qty = contract.functions.transfer(address_to, data.amount).estimate_gas({'from': address_from})
        txn = {
            'nonce': nonce,
            'to': contract_address,
            'value': 0,
            'gas': gas_qty,
            'gasPrice': client.eth.gas_price,
            'data': contract.encodeABI(fn_name='transfer', args=[address_to, data.amount])
        }
        signed_tx = client.eth.account.sign_transaction(txn, data.private_key)
        tx_hash = client.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
        return {"txid": tx_hash.hex()}
    except BaseException as ex:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(ex))
```

address_from balance:

1. Ethereum - 0.05
2. USDT - 100

gas - 63173

gasPrice - 20264381660

amount - 10

When I try to send I get error: "{'code': -32000, 'message': 'insufficient funds for gas * price + value'}".

Can anybody help me?

Comment: It's true that you don't have enough funds to buy 20 billion gallons of gas.  Where did that number come from?

Comment: 20264381660 - wei, in gwei - 20,26438166. client.eth.gas_price return this price.